# Matrix completion algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization

I am trying to implement the algorithm presented in [this paper](http://perception.csl.illinois.edu/matrix-rank/Files/robust_stereo.pdf) which tries to recover a matrix that represent a less noisier dataset of the intensities of the pixels of a set of images. In this case the noise comes from the specularities and shadows of the material of the objects in the images.

I have little (or no) experience in convex optimization. My question is, what should the stopping criterion be in the algorithm?

I was using the $||A_{i+1}-A_{i}||_F$ where $F$ denotes the Frobenius norm and checking the difference between the current and previous recovered matrix $A$ but it results that the value of that norm remains the same iteration after iteration.

Can someone give me some advise to be able to implement the algorithm?

**EDIT**

After recoded the algorithm, I check both conditions as suggested in one of the answers and this is what the plots look like.

For $||E_{i+1}-E_{i}||_F$ I'm getting
[image: Difference between the norm of E]

For $||A_{i+1}-A_{i}||_F$ I'm getting
[image: Difference between the norm of A]

I don't know where the error could be, I went step by step over the code and it seems right to me.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how this algorithm works exactly, but I guess that $||A_i-A_{i+1}||_F \leq \epsilon_A$ is a fairly reasonable stopping criterion, but also $||E_i-E_{i+1}||_F \leq \epsilon_E$ seems to be needed.

If both  $||A_i-A_{i+1}||_F $ and $||E_i-E_{i+1}||_F $ do not decrease, then you are making some big mistake in the two inner loops of the algorithms.

Comment: I checked my implementation many times and the behavior of both norms as you suggested, you can see my edit to see what the plots look like.

Comment: It seems that $||A_i-A_{i+1}||_F$ is still changing...so why should you stop?

Comment: Anyway, I would check the solution against a general purpose convex optimizer (as MOSEK) so to have a safe comparison and to be sure your algorithm is correct.

Comment: Is there some matlab tool that can help me solve the convex optimization problem that's shown in [here](http://perception.csl.illinois.edu/matrix-rank/stereo.html), namely $min_{A,E} ||A||_* + \lambda||E||_1 s.t. D = A+E$

Comment: Actually, after reading the code of [SVT](http://svt.stanford.edu) and the code of [ALM Method](http://perception.csl.illinois.edu/matrix-rank/sample_code.html#MC) the authors use the ratio between the observed values and the recovered matrix. I'll try that, although, I don't know what does that mean.

Comment: you can use cvx+mosek: http://cvxr.com/